# Is there a way to update my empty image? Edited in another program, saved

Tags: image

I edited my empty image in Clip Studio, saved it, and when I go back to Blender, it doesn't refresh. Is there a way to refresh it or do I have to save it as a different file, and then drag it into blender, and then move and scale it to where I want it to be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can find path to external data in *File > External Data > Find missing file*

or in the Texture paint or UV editing under *image > Reload (Alt+R)*